# Direct3D11 GL_RGBA4 equivalent?

Tags: direct3d, direct3d9, direct3d11

Is there an equivalent GL_RGBA4 texture format for D3D11, I can't seem to find it.
There is DXGI_FORMAT_B5G6R5_UNORM and DXGI_FORMAT_B5G5R5A1_UNORM 16 bit formats, but not the 4444 one.

Even D3D9 has all of them, so I don't understand why D3D11 would not...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i'm using the old D3D11 SDK and it is called "DXGI_FORMAT_B4G4R4A4_UNORM" in the Windows 8 SDK.